# Globally readable configuration, updated from only specific classes

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton, observer-pattern, mediator

My C#7 app boils down to a giant state machine with three possible states. Quite a few of my objects need knowledge of the current state because they act differently during different states. As in, I may flip visibility of text boxes during different states, or I may alter what an action does based on the state. I believe my question targets specific design patterns in C# more than my framework of choice, but I am using the WPF. I will add this tag on request.

I wish to *move away from* global accessibility for the state enumerable (*Singleton pattern*). So I made my top-level container, `MainViewModel`, into a **Dependency Injection** container, and only inject my state enumerable into those objects that need to know the state. I came to a solution that resembles the following:

```cs
enum MachineState
{
    SensingInputs,
    Inactive,
    Outputting,
}
class Status
{
    public MachineState state = MachineState.SensingInputs;
    public RequestToUpdate(MachineState state)
        {
            bool validTimeToChange = FunctionNotDefinedHere(state);
            if (validTimeToChange) this.state = state;
        }
}
class MainViewModel
{
    Status status;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        status = new Status();
        MyClass1 object1 = new MyClass1(status);
        MyClass2 object2 = new MyClass2();
        MyClass3 object3 = new MyClass3(status);
    }
}
```

The problem is, anyone who has a reference to it in order to read the current state also has access to any public ways to mutate the current state (`RequestToUpdate(Status)`). I only want a subset of my classes to be able to modify `Status`. This, at first, seemed to me like the ideal case for the **Observer pattern**:

```cs
class Status
{
    public MachineState state = MachineState.SensingInputs;
    public handleRequestToUpdate(Object sender, MachineStateEventArgs e)
        {
            bool validTimeToChange = FunctionNotDefinedHere(e.state);
            if (validTimeToChange) this.state = e.state;
        }
}
class MainViewModel
{
    Status status;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        status = new Status();
        MyClass1 object1 = new MyClass1(status);
        MyClass2 object2 = new MyClass2();
        MyClass3 object3 = new MyClass3(status);
        object3.RequestToUpdate += status.handleRequestToUpdate;
    }
}
```

But this solution seems ugly. I would have to declare `event RequestToUpdate` and a method to raise it like `OnRequestToUpdate()` in each class I want to modify `Status`. Additionally, each of these classes would require knowledge of `MachineStateEventArgs` This amount of repeated boilerplate bothers me, but I can't quite place it. Maybe it breaks Single Responsibility Principle / encapsulation.

So Observer pattern has failed me. My next thought was to try the **Mediator pattern** to encapsulate all this code into one class, exposing `executeRequestToUpdate(Status)` only to those classes in which it is dependency injected:

```cs
class Status // Status is same as Observer pattern above
{
    public MachineState state = MachineState.SensingInputs;
    public handleRequestToUpdate(Object sender, MachineStateEventArgs e)
        {
            bool validTimeToChange = FunctionNotDefinedHere(e.state);
            if (validTimeToChange) this.state = e.state;
        }
}
class StatusMediator
{
    public StatusMediator(Status status)
    {
        RequestToUpdate += status.handleRequestToUpdate;
    }
    public event EventHandler<RequestToUpdateEventArgs> RequestToUpdate;
    public executeRequestToUpdate(MachineState state)
    {
        RequestToUpdateEventArgs e = new RequestToUpdateEventArgs()
        RequestToUpdate?.Invoke(this, e); 
    }
}
class MainViewModel
{
    Status status;
    StatusMediator mediator;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        status = new Status();
        mediator = new StatusMediator(status);
        MyClass1 object1 = new MyClass1(status);
        MyClass2 object2 = new MyClass2();
        MyClass3 object3 = new MyClass3(status, mediator);
    }
}
```

This is the least ugly solution I have come up with on my own. I do not know the correct terminology to type into Google to find other examples, but I doubt that my problem is unique. Community, is there a better way to solve my issue? I think a thread safe solution using immutable variables would be better, but I am less confident on how I would implement that.

Comment: By the way your both pattern implementations are wrong.

Comment: Oh, um, if someone wants to redo my code to help future visitors see the correct implementation they have my permission. I guess I do not know the correct implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just rely on encapsulation and declare two interfaces to expose different responsibilities of the `Status` object.

```
interface IReadOnlyStatus
{
    MachineState State { get; }
}

interface IStatus : IReadOnlyStatus
{
    void RequestToUpdate(MachineState state);
}

public class Status : IStatus
{
    MachineState State { get; private set; }
    void RequestToUpdate(MachineState state)
    {
        bool validTimeToChange = FunctionNotDefinedHere(state);
        if (validTimeToChange) this.State = state;
    }
}
```

From there, you can just inject one or the other as needed:

```
// Can only read status
class MyClass1
{
    MyClass1(IReadOnlyStatus status)
    {

    }
}

// Can read and update status
class MyClass3
{
    MyClass3(IStatus status)
    {

    }
}

class MainViewModel
{
    Status status;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        status = new Status();
        // The cast is not necessary but added for clarity
        MyClass1 object1 = new MyClass1((IReadOnlyStatus)status);
        MyClass3 object3 = new MyClass3((IStatus)status);
    }
}
```

In the unlikely case you would want "reading" and "writing" to be completely separate responsibilities, you could just remove the inheritance between the two interfaces.